# How to avoid null with lock statement?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xmlreader, parallel.foreach, activereports

I have a method that will parallel load and run a report layout. All reports will use the same `baselayout.xml`. Since the threads failed with an exception each time they try to access the same resource I used a `lock` to lock the file.

```
public static XmlTextReader LoadReport(string reportName)
{
    object _locker = new object();
    object reportData;
    lock (_locker)
    {
        reportData = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(reportName);
    }
    return new XmlTextReader(new MemoryStream((byte[])reportData));
}
```

The parallel method looks like this:

```
private void RunReportsParallel(List<ReportObject> coverterList)
{
    try
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(coverterList, (currentObject) => {
            currentObject.Convert();
        });    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        smlLogger.Error(Helper.SetLogLine(e.Message, processId));
        throw;
    }
}
```

Conver will run following code:

```
public override SectionReport GetMainReport()
{
    SectionReport mainReport = new SectionReport();
    XMLDataSource datasource = new XMLDataSource(null, "//AkontoRechnung");
    datasource.LoadXML(rechnungsdaten.ToString());
    mainReport = new ReportAkontorechnung(datasource, reportConfiguration, Language, NoPrintOut);
    try
    {
        mainReport.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        smlLogger.Error(Helper.SetLogLine(string.Format("Error creating Report: {0}", e.Message), processId));
        throw;
    }
    return mainReport;
}
```

Line that throws the error in `ReportAkontorechnung.cs`:

`this.LoadLayout(Helper.LoadReport("ReportAkontoZusammenfassung"));` And finally, the error:

```
bei GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Controls.Image.Load(Stream stream, Boolean checkMagic)
bei GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.#Pyb(XmlNode node)
bei GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.#Qyb(XmlDocument layoutDoc, Boolean checkNames)
bei GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.LoadLayout(XmlReader reader, ArrayList& errors)
bei GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.LoadLayout(XmlReader reader)   
bei GFPrinting.Domain.ReportAkontorechnung.InitializeReport() 
     in C:\Dev\GFPrinting\Ruf.GFPrinting\branch\Concurrent\trunc\Source\SMLPrinting\Domain\ReportAkontorechnung.cs:Zeile 108.
bei GFPrinting.Domain.ReportAkontorechnung..ctor(XMLDataSource reportNavigation, ReportConfiguration reportConfiguration, String reportLanguage, Boolean noPrintout) 
     in C:\Dev\GFPrinting\Ruf.GFPrinting\branch\Concurrent\trunc\Source\SMLPrinting\Domain\ReportAkontorechnung.cs:Zeile 79.
bei GFPrinting.Domain.Akontorechnung.GetMainReport() 
    in C:\Dev\GFPrinting\Ruf.GFPrinting\branch\Concurrent\trunc\Source\SMLPrinting\Domain\Change\Akontorechnung.cs:Zeile 42.
bei GFPrinting.Domain.Change.ReportObject.Convert() 
    in C:\Dev\GFPrinting\Ruf.GFPrinting\branch\Concurrent\trunc\Source\SMLPrinting\Domain\Change\ReportObject.cs:Zeile 33.
bei GFPrinting.Domain.Rechnungshandler.<>c.<RunReportsParallel>b__13_0(ReportObject currentObject) 
    in C:\Dev\GFPrinting\Ruf.GFPrinting\branch\Concurrent\trunc\Source\SMLPrinting\Domain\Change\Rechnungshandler.cs:Zeile 103.
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass31_0`2.<ForEachWorker>b__0(Int32 i)
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object)
```

> Message:
>
> Inner Exception 1: NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde
>    nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt. Der Objektverweis wurde nicht
>    auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
>    (The object reference does not point to an object instance.)

How can I resolve the issue of returning `null`?
**Edit**: 
Liam's comment seems to resolve most issues. Not using parallel loading, but parallel running. I was to fixated on the error to see such an option.

Comment: I didn't read all the code, but the lock in `LoadReport` seems wrong. You are creating a new object within the function and use it as lock guard. This means that every time the function is called, you lock on a different object: your program will never have to wait. you need to move the declaration of `_locker` outside the function body

Comment: Fair point, thank you

Comment: If you having to lock the resource whats the point in trying to run this in Parrellel? This sounds like your just using excess threads/overhead for literally no gain. You can likely just make this all go away by running you methods in sequence.

Comment: The effective `Run()` method is the expensive part. But in order to get to this point it must first load the layout.

Comment: What is the actual message of the exception? You seem to of included the stack trace but not the message?

Comment: Why don't you load the "report" upfront then pass this into your parallel tasks then? You really need to avoid `lock` in parallel process wherever possible

Comment: @Peter if you correctly write that `lock`, it will prevent *any* kind of parallel processing as it wraps. The code will be *slower* than a simple `foreach` due to the overhead of both locking and the `Parallel.ForEach` code that sets up tasks, partitions input etc. It will be a small delay but it *will* be slower than the sequential loop

Comment: @Peter what does `ReportAkontorechnung` and `ReportAkontorechnung.Run` do anyway? It's *those* that call ActiveReports and cause the exception. The call stack shows that the exception is thrown by `ReportAkontorechnung.InitializeReport()` when it calls `ActiveReports.SectionReport.LoadLayout`, not the code you posted

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos `Run()` fires to the base class `SectionReport` of which implementation details are omitted. It renders a report.

Comment: @Peter and throws an exception in a method you haven't posted. `ResourceManager.GetObject` is thread-safe anyway. The call stack clearly shows that the exception was thrown by an ActiveReports method that was called in `InitializeReport`. That method is `LoadLayout`

Comment: It's on the line of `LaodLayout()`

Comment: @Peter which you haven't posted. Forget about GetObject, forget about the entire `ResourceManager` object. The docs clearly say [This type is threadsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netframework-4.7.2#thread-safety). The error you posted says the exception was NOT thrown by that method so trying to put a lock there is pointless.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, I tried to limit the displayed resources for clarity. And apparantly omitted important details. `InitializeReport()` has been around for longer than me and believe me: You don't want to see all of it.

Comment: @Peter then you can't get any help. That's where the error is caused, that's where you need to put breakpoints and check how that XmlReader is created, what it contains and whether it points to invalid data or paths. The final method in that call stack is `GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Controls.Image.Load(Stream stream, Boolean checkMagic)`, which was called by `GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.#Pyb(XmlNode node)` so it could be that whatever is in that node caused `Image.Load` to throw

Comment: @Peter you could check the `Locals` Watch window while debugging. When the exception is thrown, it may contain the values of variables that are local at that point, eg the stream or node. You may be able to see what's null or weird-looking there

Answer (score 6):

You are acquiring lock on a local object! 
Declare _locker as private static object in the class (If lock is required to work within instance, don't use static. But if lock is required to work upon all the instances of this class then use static.)

```
private static readonly object _locker = new object(); //readonly to avoid reassignment. static to lock on all instances.
```

And then take lock on `_locker` as

```
lock(_locker)
{

}
```

Although there could be ways to do lock free parallel reporting.

Comment: This really needs a better explanation as to why OP should do this. Why `static`? Why is this important, etc.

Comment: The OP should use `private static readonly Object _lock = new Object()` to prevent reassignment.

Comment: @peter The problem is not related to locking, you can remove the lock and the exception should still be same.

Answer (score 1):

This would be very striaghtforward with a bit of PLINQ. Start with the names, map them to resources in sequence, then map the resources to their processed output in parallel.

Might look a little like this:

```
const string[] reportNames = { "ReportA", "ReportB" };
var results = reportNames
    .AsSequential()
    .Select
    (
        name => Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(name)
    )
    .AsParallel()
    .Select
    ( 
        reportData => DoSomethingCpuBound
        (
            new XmlTextReader(new MemoryStream((byte[])reportData))
        )
    )
    .ToList();
```

This way the resources will be loaded in sequence but the processing occurs in parallel. Also, this solution completely sidesteps any threading issues, so will not require any locks.

Note: The `AsSequential()` call isn't really needed (sequential is the default) but I put it there for illustrative purposes.

Comment: `AsSequential` isn't needed as that part will run synchronously anyway. It's the query *after* `AsParallel()` that will be parallelized. In any case, the call stack shows that the error isn't thrown by `ResourceManager.GetObject()`. That method is thread safe anyway